# Datatable legacy reinitialization issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using legacy datatable . i am initializing datatable on button click like

```
    $('#Tableid').dataTable({
                   "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                    "oTableTools": {
                        "sSwfPath": "../admin/assets/plugins/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
                    },
                    "bDestroy":true,
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": ajaxSource,
                    "fnServerData": fnDataTablesPipeline,
                    "aaSorting": [[0,'asc']],
                    aoColumns: [
                    { mData: "col1", },
                    { mData: "col2", },
                    { mData: "col3", },
                    { mData: "col4", },
                    { mData: "col5", },
                    ]
                })
```

i am passing some values on button click that changes the datatable. Problem is i want to reintialize the same table on same button click. I tried using "bDestroy" that removes the warning but doesn't get the data. Please help

Comment: There is missing value after `"bServerSide":` and lots of trailing commas. Otherwise `bDestroy` should do the trick. If all you change is parameters sent to the server, then there is no need to re-initialize the table, you just need to reload the data - for older jQuery DataTables 1.9, use [fnAjaxReload](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnReloadAjax), for newer [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()).